# How can i impove my code?

Tags: c#, networking

Because I have no experience with sockets and I don't know how to make one, I have this code:

```
public void getGameInfo()
{
     string content;
     do
     {
          WebClient client = new WebClient();
          client.DownloadFile(fileadress, filename);
          client.Dispose();
          StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filename);
          content = reader.ReadToEnd();
          reader.Close();
     } while (content == "");
     File.Delete(filename);
     string[] lines = content.Split(separator, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
     mode = zeilen[0];
     gameInfo = new string[line.Length-1];
     Array.Copy(lines, 1, gameInfo, 0, lines.Length-1);
}
```

It connects to a Apache server with a .txt file and reads it. But if too many Programms (three) uses the code, it will throw a WebException.
So is there a way to improve this, or a guide to make a socket for this?

Edit 1:
And what if I want to write to the file like this function?

```
public void setSpielInfo(int line, string input)
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    string content;
    do
    {
        client.DownloadFile(gameadress, filename);
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filename);
        content = reader.ReadToEnd();
        reader.Close();
    } while (content == "");

    string[] lines = content.Split(separator, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    lines[zeile+1] = input;
    byte[] bytearray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines)); // I've read that byte arrays are faster than string arrays

    FileStream writer = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Truncate);
    writer.Write(bytearray, 0, bytearray.Length);
    writer.Close();

    client.UploadFile(ftpAdress, filename);
    client.Dispose();
    File.Delete(filename);
}
```

Comment: I would recommend you to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to read `string`, right? So why do you download file?

```
  string content;

  // Do not dispose explicitly, wrap into using instead  
  using (WebClient client = new WebClient()) {
    content = client.DownloadString(fileadress);
  }

  string[] lines = content.Split(separator, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

  mode = lines.FirstOrDefault();    // 1st line
  gameInfo = lines.Skip(1).ToArray();  // all the others
```

You can further shorten the code into

```
  using (WebClient client = new WebClient()) {
    var lines = client
      .DownloadString(fileadress)  
      .Split(separator, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    mode = lines.FirstOrDefault();
    gameInfo = lines.Skip(1).ToArray();
  }
```

**Edit:** again, what do you actually want to perform: download a `string`, write file, upload the file:

```
  string content;

  // Do not dispose explicitly, wrap into using instead  
  using (WebClient client = new WebClient()) {
    // Download string (text) 
    content = client.DownloadString(fileadress);
    // Write the text to file (override existing if it is)
    File.WriteAllText(filename, content);
    // Upload file
    // think on uploading the string - client.UploadString(ftpAdress, content);
    client.UploadFile(ftpAdress, filename); 
  }

  string[] lines = content.Split(separator, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

  mode = lines.FirstOrDefault();    // 1st line
  gameInfo = lines.Skip(1).ToArray();  // all the others
```

As the further improvent think on working with `string` not files:

```
  using (WebClient client = new WebClient()) {
    // Download string (text) 
    content = client.DownloadString(fileadress);
    client.UploadString(ftpAdress, content);
  }
```